# Generate a random string with length inherited from variable

Tags: c#, encryption, cryptography

I am working on a cryptography console application (C#) and want to include an option for the Vigenere Cipher during the encryption process to generate a One-Time Pad key that is completely random letters(A-Z) but the same length (in characters) of the message to be encrypted.  So the question is how do I generate a random string with the same length of previous user input (Stringbuilder s)?  I apologize in advance if this is an obvious solution.  The following is my code for initializing and displaying the results of the encryption process.  The nested "if" is where I want to generate the One-Time Pad key if the user enters "gen-otp":

```
//Encrypt
if ((selection == 1) && (type == 1))
{
    Clear();
    WriteLine("\nPlease enter the message you wish to encrypt(please exclude spaces from the message):\n");
    StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder(ReadLine());
    WriteLine("\nPlease enter your key word or phrase:\n");
    string key = ReadLine();
    VigenereEncryptDecrypt.VigenereEncrypt(ref s, key);
    if (ReadLine() == "gen-otp") 
    { 
    }
    Clear();
    WriteLine("\nEncrypted message:\n{0}\n\nKey: {1}\n\nPlease press ENTER to continue:", s, key);
    ReadLine();
    Clear();
    CipherSelection();
}
```

Comment: I am thinking I will need to declare another variable inside of the nested if to hold the randomly generated key instead of trying to turn the existing variable "key" into the randomly generated key?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So the question is how do I generate a random string with the same length of previous user input(Stringbuilder s)

For random letter `A-Z`

```
Random rnd = new Random();
var otp = string.Concat(Enumerable.Range(0, s.Length)
                                  .Select(i => (char)(rnd.Next(26) + 'A')));
```

Comment: But for encryption you ought to use the Crypto random generator.

Comment: @Sylvester_Sneer In case you haven't  read it yet http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: I had to look that up. But still, as this is a learning exercise it should at least be mentioned.